# How can i serialize manytomany django models using DRF

Tags: django, web-services, serialization

How can i get products name and id instead of pro_id and ord_id in output ? but not in string type. for example : "name : somebook" is not a valid option for me. 
I just working on this for 2 days without break and i think im missing a little detail but i cant find what is it.

**Output i want**

```
[
  {
"order_id": 1,
"totalquantity": 12,
"totalprice": 56,
"userid": 1,
"customerAddress": "evka1",
"customerPhone": "539",
"trackNo": 12034,
"products": [
  {
    "name": "somebook",
    "id": 1,
    "quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "someotherbook",
    "id": 2,
    "quantity": 6
  }
]
  }
]
```

**Output i get**

```
[
  {
"order_id": 1,
"totalquantity": 12,
"totalprice": 56,
"userid": 1,
"customerAddress": "evka1",
"customerPhone": "539",
"trackNo": 12034,
"products": [
  {
    "pro_id": 2,
    "ord_id": 1,
    "quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "pro_id": 3,
    "ord_id": 1,
    "quantity": 6
  }
]
  }
]
```

**Order model**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    totalquantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    totalprice = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    userid = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    trackNo = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    billNo = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    customerAddress = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="nil", null=True)
    customerPhone = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="nil", null=True)
```

**Order Serializer**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
products = ProductOrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ('order_id', 'totalquantity', 'totalprice', 'userid', 'customerAddress', 'customerPhone', 'trackNo', 'products')
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="nil", null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="nil", null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    soldcount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="nil", null=True)
```

**Product Serializer**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'author', 'date', 'price', 'quantity', 'soldcount', 'category')
```

**ProductOrder Model**

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):

    pro_id = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
    ord_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

**ProductOrder Serializer**

```
class ProductOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ProductOrder
    fields = ('pro_id', 'ord_id', 'quantity')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you desired can be achieved with nested serializers in django-rest-framework,

But, it needs some refactoring in your models,

You need to add a ForeignKey to the model ProductOrder towards the Product model, inorder to attain a ManyToMany relation,

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    pro_id = models.ForeinKey(Product, related_name='orders', default=0,null=True)
    ord_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='products')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

Also, in your serializers,

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'quantity')


class ProductOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = ProductSerializer(source='pro_id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductOrder
        fields = ('details', )


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductOrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('totalquantity', 'totalprice', 'userid',
              'trackNo', 'billNo', 'customerAddress', 'customerPhone',
              'products')
```

You could call OrderSerializer and get the output as you desired,

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    serializer = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The output will be like this,

```
[
    {
        "totalquantity": 0,
        "totalprice": 0,
        "userid": 0,
        "trackNo": 0,
        "billNo": 0,
        "customerAddress": "nil",
        "customerPhone": "nil",
        "products": [
            {
                "details": {
                    "name": "nil",
                    "id": 1,
                    "quantity": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "details": {
                    "name": "nil",
                    "id": 1,
                    "quantity": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem when i changed ProductOrderSerializer to :

```
class ProductListingSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        dict={}
        dict['name'] = value.pro_id.name
        dict['id'] = value.pro_id.pk
        dict['quantity'] = value.quantity
        return dict
```

but im in "my code works i don't know why" situation now :D